# Change the container screen from button in the same screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am Making an App with a custom bottom bar. I have made a screen having two containers in a stack one container is the Screens changer and the second container is a bottomMenuBar. I am changing the screens easily from bottomMenuBar container but inside one of the child screens i want to change the the whole screen from a button. please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie9Kw.png)

Comment: You can have boolean variable and show 2 screens conditionally like:
showFirstScreen ? FirstScreen : SecondScreen.
And on your button click, toggle the value of showFirstScreen .

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement:

```dart
FlatButton(
  child: Text('Third Screen'),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ThirdScreen()));
  },
),
```